# attempting to paint over a darker colour of paint

Tags: painting

trying to paint a bedroom, that has been papered and previously painted , but the paint won't stick to the wall , its all patchy I let it dry for a few days, tried again but the roller is just removing paint, or its just not taking any paint

Answer (score 1):

The walls need to be prepared first.

Light sand and then TSP cleaner over all the walls.  If the old paint is oil based, you then need a coat of primer before you paint.

Comment: +1 for the mentioning of TSP. Another good suggestion is the primer. Make sure you use a good "High Cover" type primer. They make some specifically for situations like this that have zinc and other bonding agents that help bond to the substrate.